# Refer to list of variables in sum function in R

Tags: r, vector, sum

I have a table that looks like the following example:

| Person | Date | VarA | VarD | VarC | VarB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Erik | 2020-12-31 | 5 | 7 | 3 | 12 |
| Erik | 2021-03-31 | 6 | 4 | 4 | 15 |
| Simon | 2020-12-31 | 9 | 8 | 5 | 17 |
| Simon | 2021-03-31 | 11 | 2 | 3 | 16 |

The number of variables in the table can vary. I want to create a general R script that can be used to calculate the ratio between the sum of any number of variables in the numerator and denominator. The list of variables and which ones that should be summed in the numerator and denominator are specified and included in the R script using {Var}, {P1} and {P2} (see code below).

I have written the following code:

```
#{Var} is replaced by a list of all variables, in this case "VarA, VarD, VarC, VarB"
Variablelist <- str_split("{Var}", ", ", simplify = TRUE)

#{P1} and {P2} are replaced by lists of the positions of the variables in Variablelist that should be included, for example "1, 3, 4"
NumeratorSum <- Variablelist[c({P1})]
DenominatorSum <- Variablelist[c({P2})]

InputDataSet <- InputDataSet %>%
  dplyr::rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(ResultRatio = sum(NumeratorSum, na.rm=TRUE) / sum(NumeratorSum, na.rm=TRUE))

OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet %>%
  dplyr::select(Person, Date, ResultRatio)
```

For example, if {P1}="1, 3, 4" and {P2}="2, 3" then the ResultRatio should be equal to sum(VarA, VarC, VarB)/sum(VarD, VarC).

However, the code is not working and I need help to understand how I should refer to the lists NumeratorSum and DenominatorSum in the sum function so that the columns in the table with the same name as the elements in those lists are summed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming DF is the input data frame as per Note at end and the inputs v, P1 and P2 shown below, use rowSums.  No packages are used.

```
v <- c("VarA", "VarB", "VarC", "VarD")
P1 <- c(1, 3, 4)
P2 <- 2:3
rowSums(DF[v[P1]]) / rowSums(DF[v[P2]])
## [1] 1.0000000 0.7368421 1.0000000 0.8421053

# check
(DF$VarA + DF$VarC + DF$VarD) / (DF$VarB + DF$VarC)
## [1] 1.0000000 0.7368421 1.0000000 0.8421053
```

If v, P1 and P2 are expressed as comma separated strings vs, p1s and p2s then use scan first:

```
vs <- "VarA, VarB, VarC, VarD"
v <- scan(text = vs, what = "", quiet = TRUE, sep = ",", strip.white = TRUE)
v
## [1] "VarA" "VarB" "VarC" "VarD"

p1s <- "1, 3, 4"
P1 <- scan(text = p1s, quiet = TRUE, sep = ",")
P1
## [1] 1 3 4

p2s <- "2, 3"
P2 <- scan(text = p2s, quiet = TRUE, sep = ",")
P2
## [1] 2 3
```

### Note

```
DF <- 
structure(list(Person = c("Erik", "Erik", "Simon", "Simon"), 
    Date = c("2020-12-31", "2021-03-31", "2020-12-31", "2021-03-31"
    ), VarA = c(5L, 6L, 9L, 11L), VarD = c(7L, 4L, 8L, 2L), VarC = c(3L, 
    4L, 5L, 3L), VarB = c(12L, 15L, 17L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```